# Unable to create reports based on activities in sfdc

Tags: apex, activities, joined-reports, cross-filter

I got a requirement like to create reports for activities.i have user able to view all accounts and Opportunities.But he can't able view all activities while creating reports.I don't where it will not work.Any help is appreciated.

Because user in a different role hierarchy.Any solutions

Comment: I found out a problem for this issue is role hierarchy.But what is the solution to this problem can anyone help me

Comment: Role hierarchy Is different.So what is the solution to this problem